# how could i update android AWS SDK to use TLS 1.2 connections?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, tls1.2

i received this message from AWS

> [ACTION REQUIRED] - Update your TLS connections to 1.2 to maintain AWS
> endpoint connectivity
>
> Please see the following for further details on the TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1
> connections detected from your account between September 15, 2022 and
> September 30, 2022 (the UserAgent may be truncated due to a limit in
> the number of characters that can be displayed):

```
Region  |    Endpoint   |   API Event Name   |   TLS Version   |   Connection Count  |   UserAgent
us-east-1 | sts.amazonaws.com | AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity | TLSv1 | 2 | aws-sdk-android/2.11.1 Linux/3.10.17-1114920 Dalvik/1.6.0/0 de_DE com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider/2.11.1
```

i read the documentation
https://aws.amazon.com/jp/blogs/security/tls-1-2-to-become-the-minimum-for-all-aws-fips-endpoints/
but on documentation does not say how to update Android SDK to use TLS 1.2 connections

someone could say me how to use TLS 1.2 connections on AWS android SDK ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [current version](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android) 2.67.0 still does not provide TLSv1.2+ support on android 21 and below.

But you can already take a look into [a side branch changes](https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/blob/tjroach/tls-upgrade/aws-android-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/http/TLS12SocketFactory.java).
This can be a good starting point of manual migration, if you don't want to wait for official release.